# Actionbar items always appear in overflow menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar-compat, splitactionbar

I am using a MainActivity derived from FragmentActivity with Fragments representing each tab
in the ActionBar. From the docs at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html, I implemented a split ActionBar with tabs on top and the remaining Action Items on the bottom part of the ActionBar. 
Because each tab's Fragment have their own specific Action Items, a menu representing these Actions is loaded when a Fragment is being called.
This works in general. However, the Action Items always appear in the Overflow Menu on the bottom part of the ActionBar, even though there is plenty of space left of it. Actually, no visible item(s) or text take up space.

I am using the support v4 library.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
TabNavigatorPagerAdapter tabNavigatorPagerAdapter;
ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
    // of the app
    tabNavigatorPagerAdapter = new TabNavigatorPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the action bar
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Specify that the Home/Up button should not be enabled, since there is no hierarchical
    // parent
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

    //force tabs at top and actions at bottom
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
    // user swipes between sections
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabNavigatorPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // When swiping between different app sections, select the corresponding tab
            // We can also use the ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference
            // to the Tab
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.

    // Add Calendar activity
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.calendar_activity).setTabListener(this));
    // Add Grocery List activity
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.grocery_list_activity).setTabListener(this));
    // Add Search activity
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.search_activity).setTabListener(this));
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

public static class TabNavigatorPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public TabNavigatorPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                // This is the Calendar section of the App
                return new CalendarFragment();
            default:
                // The other sections of the app are dummy placeholders
                Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Section " + (position + 1);
    }
}

// The Calendar fragment
public static class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        ((TextView)  rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(R.string.calendar_activity);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_calendar, menu);
    }
}
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"/>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CollectionDemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/demo_collection">

    </activity>
</application>
```

Calendar menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myfirstapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.kikicorp.myfirstapp.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/qwe"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    myfirstapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="qwe">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/ee"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
    myfirstapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="edit">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/xx"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    myfirstapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="new">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/go_crazy"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    myfirstapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/go_crazy_action">
</item>
</menu>
```

Result screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the native action bar, as indicated by the fact that you are inheriting from `FragmentActivity`, not `ActionBarActivity`. Hence, `myfirstapp:showAsAction` will be ignored. Use `android:showAsAction` for the native action bar.

If you are intending to use `appcompat-v7` for the action bar backport, then change your class to inherit from `ActionBarActivity`, not `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: When I use android:showAsAction, the Android Studio IDE marks this as an error, advising to reference from my own namespace, in this case myfirstapp. When I ignore it and run the app, it works exactly as I want. Thanks for solving this problem! Too bad the IDE gave me wrong advice...

Comment: I use myfirstapp:showAsAction, appcompat-v7, inherit from ActionBarActivity  and I see the overflow menu lik the image. How can I force to show the overflow menu in the top bar?

Comment: @MARM: Remove the `splitActionBarWhenNarrow` from your manifest. That should not be working with modern versions of `appcompat-v7` anyway, last I checked.

Comment: @MARM: Then your action bar will not look like the picture, which shows a split action bar and the overflow menu in the bottom action bar portion. You may wish to open your own Stack Overflow question, where you post your own manifest and your own screenshot, so people can help you with your specific problem.